# Can’t boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, freeze

I’m new to this Linux stuff first time switching. 
It took me almost 48 hours to download everything properly to my USB, loads of reinstalling and watching tons of confusing guides. I manage to finally make the USB to boot to something but it just gets stuck on this screen. I’m able to access recovery from the Ubuntu select screen, I tried the dpkg thing and the others listed but nothing fixed the issue. I seen people say it might have to do with graphics or something? I have AMD integrated graphics on my pc. I get the Ubuntu loading screen then it goes to the image I posted.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sulpA.jpg

Comment: Some text appeared underneath after like 10 minutes, I think I might have to wait it out?

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of your post yesterday.

Comment: I had the exact same issue on my computer after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.10. I have an Nvidia GTX 1070, and I had the Nvidia drivers installed when I did the upgrade. I would recommend downloading the LTS version of Ubuntu, especially if you're new. The LTS release is usually much more stable and has fewer problems like this.

Comment: On your install USB/CD, does the "Try Ubuntu" environment work properly?

Comment: I have two usbs, one has the iso and the one on the screen is the usb with Ubuntu installed. I am able to load up Try Ubuntu with the other USB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.